# Error while installing ruby using rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

Am getting the below error while trying to install ruby using rvm:

```
$rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system..................................................................................................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p448',
please read /home/troy/.rvm/log/1379872584_ruby-1.9.3-p448/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Can you help me on this!

Comment: Read the log like it says. If that doesn't help, post a (small) snippet from the log that shows the root error.

Comment: Do check the log file mentioned in the error message - `/home/troy/.rvm/log/1379872584_ruby-1.9.3-p448/update_system.log` ; it could have something useful.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later. For 404 errors check your sources configured in: /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Comment: Thanks Jim,, The issue is resolved (Thanks, the issue was launchpad ppa was not updating and henceforth was not allowing ruby to install { ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/}  So removed it from the update list... everything went smooth :))

Comment: @user1482084 I removed it from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list and everything works find. thank you.

Answer (score 45):

Remove broken or 404 repos from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

`rvm` will fail if you don't remove or comment them out.

To work out which aren't working, run `apt-get update` and see which ones are marked as failing.

Once you are using `rvm`, installing Ruby is easy.

`rvm install ruby`

`rvm use ruby --default`

I had the same problem.

Comment: Looked through various questions on the subject and this one fixed it for me. Commenting out the missing routes in the sources.list did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me too! I had a stupid ppa source list on debian that was ruining ruby installation. Thanks. PS: I looked for it on /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: it worked for me too... i mean, i go to sources.list.d and removed a broken package, that appeared when i typed ```sudo apt-get update``` so i removed it as root user and it's fine now.

Comment: Great! Many thanks, it works! Found here how to remove 404 https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 13):

It isn't unusual to not have a binary package for you distribution, and `rvm` should try to install from source.

First, check that it didn't actually install it:

```
rvm list
```

Otherwise, I suspect you may be missing some depedencies, which you can find with:

```
rvm requirements
```

You'll need to install those and the run the install again.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but I want to install a versino on ruby on a server in which the user that uses rvm has no permission to do sudo apt-get update. Is there a way I can see te requirements without sudo?

Comment: Running rvm requirements worked like a charm in my local machine. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

make sure you can update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then start rvm installation again.

#### Update 1:

also it looks like you are using old version of rvm, make sure to update rvm before continuing:

```
rvm get stable
```

Comment: can you mention all the steps to install ruby using rvm... step-by-step...? (if possible)

Comment: there is no more steps then just updating rvm and then installing ruby, it is crucial that you read all the outputs and mentioned log files - the information is there

Comment: Thanks, the issue was launchpad ppa was not updating and henceforth was not allowing ruby to install { ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/}  So removed it from the update list... everything went smooth :)

Answer (score 2):

been having a similar problem and discovered a typo in grizzly.list file

http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.cononical.com precise-updates/grizzly

should have been

http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/grizzly

i.e. first a in canonical

is this mistake part of the ubuntu 12.04 distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you run sudo apt-get update, all your PPAs are updating correctly. If not, remove them or edit them so they do so (you might need to change the distribution, for example, from raring to lucid. You can do this through terminal or Software Center. [This](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-use-launchpad-ppa-add-remove.html) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280462/errors-when-running-apt-get-update) should help)

Comment: You should include some of the details in your links into your answer

Answer (score 1):

When you are initially installing rvm, read the notes. For suppose you get notes like,

create a   * WARNING: You have `'~/.profile'` file, you might want to load it,
      to do that add the following line to `'/home/name/.bash_profile':source ~/.profile`

Then-> `$ sudo gedit /home/name/.bash_profile`

```
   Add line `~/.profile` to the file. Save and close it.
```

now run  `$ rvm` requirements 
You should get a success message.

Answer (score 1):

**RVM will not install ruby if apt-get is failing**. I had the same issue and noticed when running `apt-get update`, it was failing on "google-chrome.list". I fixed it following these directions and was then able to successfully run `apt-get update`, which then allowed me to run `rvm install ruby`.

1. Edit google-chrome.list (assuming you’re on the Stable Channel):

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

2. In the text file that opens edit the file so that the line reads:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

3. Try to update again:

`sudo apt-get update`

4. Try to run RVM again:

`rvm install ruby`

Answer (score 1):

this problem caused in `apt-get update` so you have to disable the PPA :

> System Settings>Software & Updates>Other Software

then reinstall.
[this image show disable PPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXvOP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and just did that:

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-3-bionic.list

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while executing the command

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --rails

It appeared to be that I was using the command as not a previleged user. So, using

```
sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --rails
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is to solve the rvm requirment error returns 100

If any deb command is commented in /etc/apt/sources.list than try to uncomment that command from /etc/apt/sources.list

Command is:

$sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

If problem is not solved than replace sources.list file with other Ubuntu's sources.list

Command is:

$mv  /etc/apt/sources.list

Please make a backup before doing that

Command is:

$cp /etc/apt/sources.list sources_backup.list

Problem should solve by this time, if not than reinstall the Ubuntu.

Note: If sources.list file is corrupted than it will gives problem to install other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the above error on installing `ruby-2.3.0` in `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Go to the file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list
```

and remove the below:

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial main
```

then run `sudo apt-get update` and after `rvm install ruby-2.3.0` it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a permission problem, solved with:

```
sudo chmod 777 log
```

Answer (score 0):

you can temporarily disable updates by this

> sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed"

[Ruby RVM apt-get update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error)