# issues when installing Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu-12.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have been trying to install Ruby On Rails on my Ubuntu-12.04 machine. I am installing through a Ubuntu blog as it was suggested by people to be a successful installation guide . But when I tried to run the command " rvm requirements ", I get

```
" Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
please read /home/arsalan/.rvm/log/1386743809/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100."
```

I have no idea of how to resolve this error . I will appreciate every help.
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Have you tried to view `update_system.log` ?

Comment: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: Thanks Gopal but I was installing from the same link .

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947072/error-while-installing-ruby-using-rvm.  Normally you need to use `rvm requirements` and install what it says is missing.

Comment: Agreed, what shows the `update_system.log` file?

Comment: what should I do with this update_system.log file .

Comment: I found that some people have edited the update_system.log file but I dont have that line of code to delete.