# Requirements Error while installing Ruby using RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, failed-installation, linux-mint

I'm getting the following error while trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM (Linux Mint 17)

A previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947072/error-while-installing-ruby-using-rvm) recommends that I "Remove broken or 404 repos from my sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list`"

The problem is that on Linux Mint 17, my sources list has only one line `#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 _Qiana_ - Release amd64 2xxxxxxx]/ trusty contrib main non-free`.

Therefore,the three broken 404 repos:

- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources` 404 not found
- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages`  404 not found
- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages`  404 not found

are not in this `sources.list` file

Can you help me on this?

```
$ rvm install ruby 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: mint/17/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p481.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for mint.
Installing requirements for mint.
Updating system................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p481',
showing last 15 lines of /home/james/.rvm/log/1xxxxxxxxx_ruby-2.0.0-p481/update_system.log
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the answer I linked to in my question,

RVM will fail if you don't remove or comment out any broken or 404 Repos from your sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list`

The problem is that for some reason, you cant get direct access to all the repos on **LinuxMint 17**... unlike Ubuntu.

I ran `sudo apt-get update`:

This will show you the broken packages at the end... For me, this was:

- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources`
  404 not found
- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages`
  404 not found
- `http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages`
  404 not found

Since I cant just comment it out because I don't have access to the full source.list (or I cant find it), I found out that in Linux Mint 17, you can use the GUI.

So I went to `Menu >> Software >> Software Sources >> PPA` to un-tick the broken Launchpad Repos.

After doing this, I ran `rvm install 2.0.0` again and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The new standard sources.list moved to
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list

And before modifications of it try to run
   sudo apt-get update

Comment: Should i just copy that into my sources.list file and remove `#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 _Qiana_ - Release amd64 2xxxxxxx]/ trusty contrib main non-free'?

Comment: I was wrong and edit the first answer, read it please. May be /etc/apt/sources.list is not needed now? Try to move it to another place and run sudo apt-get update and after it try to run rvm install again.

Comment: I just tried it, I'm still getting the same error (Linux Mint 17)

Comment: Also, you can try this: # sudo apt-get install curl, # \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby, # rvm install 2.1.1

Comment: I've fixed it. I'll post a solution once ruby finishes installing (fingers crossed it will work this time)... Thanks for your help.